# How to edit GridView-button Size

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a Gridview that have Buttons. Now, my case is to decrease the size of button and I just cant find a way to do it. So maybe you can help me a bit for this.. Tnx!

Sample code below:

```
<Columns>
 <asp:ButtonField  ButtonType="Button" Text="ADD" CommandName="addrow"/>
</Columns>
```

Btw I also tried putting CSS -width:N/em; but it modifies the cell-size not the button-size

Comment: Check in MSDN here : [ButtonField Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfield.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an `ItemStyle-CssClass` property to your `ButtonField`:

```
<Columns>
 <asp:ButtonField ItemStyle-CssClass="gvbutton" ButtonType="Button" Text="ADD" CommandName="addrow" />
</Columns>
```

And then add some css along the lines of:

```
.gvbutton input {
     width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: this is what I did before..But i still tried it and still the cell size is the one the gets modified.. what i need is to modify the button size

Comment: Your css had the class followed by `input`? That's the key to getting it applied to the button itself.

Comment: AFTER PUTTING INPUT IT WORKED LIKE A CHARM TNX!